# Android - store image on a temp file cross-activity

Tags: android, bitmap, temporary-files

In the app I am developing, I have an activity in which I show two **ImageViews** made of two bitmaps, `ca.bm` and `ca.tempBm` respectively. It works fine on my device but produces **OutOfMemoryError** on some devices when trying to copy the original bitmap to the bitmap I will modify later:

```
ca.tempBm = Bitmap.createBitmap(ca.bm);   // out of memory error
```

I would like to create a temp file instead to hold the original image and work with a single bitmap, but the temp file must be preserved when changing from the Camera Activity to the next activity and should be destroyed only when the second activity does.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a Bitmap to the cache directory with:

```
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(getCacheDir(), "tempBMP"));
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, outStream);
outStream.close();
```

And read back in with:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmapPath.getAbsolutePath());
```

But you might be better off just saving memory by creating a smaller Bitmap, drawing the larger Bitmap to the smaller Bitmap's canvas, then passing around the smaller Bitmap between Activities.